# Different output between sum and +

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a problem that consists basically on sum all the rows based on their ID and sum some specific variables to get a consolidated dataset to input on another work, but there is an issue with the sum function and I'd appreciate some explanation about this.

Dataset:

```
teste <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2),
                    VALUE = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                    MOD = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

  ID VALUE MOD
1  1    10   1
2  1    10   1
3  2    10   1
4  1    10   1
5  3    10   1
6  3    10   1
7  2    10   1
```

Using + operator:

```
teste %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(CONS = VALUE + MOD)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID VALUE   MOD  CONS
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    30     3    33
2     2    20     2    22
3     3    20     2    22
```

Using *sum* function:

```
teste %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(CONS = sum(VALUE, MOD))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID VALUE   MOD  CONS
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    30     3    77
2     2    20     2    77
3     3    20     2    77
```

Comment: `sum(VALUE, MOD)` is to calculate sum of `VALUE` and `MOD` combined, i.e. (30,20,20) + (3,2,2)

Comment: But my intention is to sum those variables, I just didn't expected that sum and + would have different methods and I don't know why that occurs.

Answer (score 2):

`summarize_all` [removes one level of grouping](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/dev/reference/summarise.html#value) so re-group it:

```
teste %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%   # <--------------------------
    mutate(CONS = sum(VALUE, MOD)) %>%
    ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID VALUE   MOD  CONS
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    30     3    33
2     2    20     2    22
3     3    20     2    22
```

Comment: I still don't get it, shouldn't sum execute a batch of + operations? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `sum` sums up all the elements in all its arguments and returns a scalar result.  For example using the builtin `BOD` try `sum(BOD)` and `sum(BOD, BOD)`